# DOD Common Access Card (CAC) Authentication

Tags: pki, x509certificate2, mod-ssl, cac

I have figured out all the necessary steps to get DOD CAC card based client certificate authentication working in Apache, but am now struggling to pull a good GUID for the user from the certificate I am receiving.  Is there a GUID available on the certificate that will not change when the CAC card is renewed?  I was thinking of using the SSL_CLIENT_S_DN which would look something like:

/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=DoD/OU=PKI/OU=CONTRACTOR/CN=LAST_NAME.FIRST_NAME.MIDDLE_NAME.0123456789

but I have heard that the number on the end changes when the CAC card is renewed.  Is this true?  Is there a better piece of information to use for a GUID?  I'd also like to get the users email address, but I don’t see it available in the information I am receiving from the certificate.  Is the email adress available in some custom extension that I am not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We have run into plenty of instances where that number on the end changes.  We were eventually beaten into using a process where that if a user gets a new CAC, we require that the user re-associate that new card with their user account.  That's the process on most DoD systems now, such as DKO (Defense Knowledge Online) and others.  If we do not have the supplied CAC certificate's data in our database, the user must log onto the system using a username and password.  If the credentials are correct, the identifying information of that CAC is associated with the user's account in the system.

At least that's how we did it.

And, as far as, getting access to the email address, @harningt is correct.  It depends on which certificate is supplied to you.

Answer (score 5):

The DOD EDI PIN should NOT change.

I can give you plenty of instances where you can go to the DOD411 site (CAC required) to look up somebody and it will show certificates from when they were a contractor and then show the same person again, now as a DOD civilian (we see this alot with new hires).

I just looked up one of our new hires who has variously been in the Air Force, then a contractor for the Navy, then a contractor for the Army, and now works for us as a DA Civilian.

Same DOD EDI PIN.

The CN (Common Name) can change (e.g. resulting from marriage), but the ten digit DOD EDI should not change.

As to what certificate to authenticate against, most sites are authenticating against the email cert, but some do use the identity cert instead.

Mike

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you've all figured out your answers by now. But for others coming to this post later just a couple notes:

This is the DISA reference site:
http://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/

PKI is the infrastructure, PKE is enabling your computers/servers/applications with PKI auth

This is the PKE admin getting started guide:

http://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/getting_started/Pages/administrators.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First, many PKI-enabled DOD sites should support hardware tokens issued through commercial CAs that participate in the DOD's ECA program (Verisign, IdenTrust, ORC). These ECA-issued certificates don't even include this "number", the DOD EDI PN.

As I understand it, there is supposed to be some effort made to keep the number stable for a particular person. For example even if I quit my civilian job at the DOD and go to work for a contractor, get married and change my name, quit my job and enlist in the Coast Guard, my DOD EDI PN should be the same. However, in practice, I doubt it works like that.

And even if it did, I probably shouldn't have the same access to an application. Each time my employment changes, the certificate on my CAC should be revoked. If an application is only looking at the common name or subject alternative name of the certificate, it will miss changes in the organization that probably affect the authorization of that subject.

Basing authentication on a particular certificate (issuer and serial number) is a pain for users, but it does make sense from a standpoint of security and robustness.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the argument for using the number on the end as the unique identifier for individuals because the other information (name, organization, etc) are the bits of information that can realistically change over time as opposed to the number. However, I have not seen an official document or any other piece of authoritative information that actually states this as a fact.

Just curious, is there a document that speaks to the step-by-step process of enabling Apache and DOD CAC? That's what actually brought me to this question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

The email address is available in the Subject Alternative Name fieldset.  This depends on CAC certificate, but that used for SSL login should contain it (it's also the email signing cert).

The subject would not likely change for a given person very often.  The number is indeed the unique number identifying a person.  This number would also be present in a UPN field in the Subject Alternative Name for windows login (in a form such as NUMBER@MIL)

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the owners SSN from the PIV.  That will not change